# ERB template add to different parts of the page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

experts

Say, I want to render a page in a kind of Online Book structure:

```
Table of contents:
[link here]1. How it all began
[link here]2. Where did it go
...

1. How it all began
    Text of chapter 1
    ...
2. Where did it go
    Text of chapter 2
    ...
...
```

So normally using erb I would do the following ruby code:

```
<h2>Table of contents:</h2>
<% chapters.each_with_index do |chapter, n| %>
   <a href="#c_<%= n %>"><%= n %>. <%= chapter.title %></a>
<% end %>
<hr/>

<% chapters.each_with_index do |chapter, n| %>
    <h2 id="c_<%= n %>"><%= n %>. <%= chapter.title %></h2>
    <p>
    <%= chapter.text %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

However, I do two identical loops here, because I have to insert ruby-code in two different parts of the page simultaneously.
Maybe there is a way to do just one loop?

Comment: I think this is perfectly fine...

Comment: It doesn't strike me as particularly problematic to have two loops in this case. You could, for instance, stash the chapter text in a variable of some kind then output that variable after the first enumerable is complete, but you're going to end up with uglier code as a result.

Comment: You do, however, have semantically incorrect markup having each ID tag used twice.

Comment: @DVG where do you see duplicate IDs?

Comment: My bad, I read that totally wrong, you don't have them :)

Comment: This can be generalized. Say you have a very long loop to draw a table for report. And on each iteration you count some values (sum up some statistics). In the end of the loop you want to put these results *on the top of the page*. Don't you think you should be able to do this without the need to run the loop once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, there is nothing wrong with what you have. Here is a very simplistic way to use just one loop:

```
<% toc, body = '', '' %>
<% @chapters.each_with_index do |chapter, n| %>
  <% toc << %Q{
    <a href="#c_#{n}">#{n}. #{chapter.title}</a>
  } %>
  <% body << %Q{
    <h2 id="c_#{n}">#{n}. #{chapter.title}</h2>
    <p>#{chapter.text}</p>
  } %>  
<% end %>
<%= raw toc %>
<hr/>
<%= raw body %>
```

You would want to ensure that everything you want to escape is escaped. You would also probably want to move this into a helper.